# yarn deletes hidden files (.metadata_never_index, .gitkeep)

Tags: yarnpkg

In my node_module folder I use to have 2 hidden files:

```
.metadata_never_index
.gitkeep
```

The first one prevents Spotlight from indexing the folder
(maybe the second file isn't really needed, but that doesn't matter for now).

In the past I used npm to install the modules.
Now i wanted to switch to yarn.
But yarn deletes these two files when using `yarn install`.

How can I prevent yarn from deleting those files in the node_modules folder?

Comment: as a workaround I added this to the scripts section in package.json:
`"postinstall": "touch node_modules/.metadata_never_index && touch node_modules/.gitkeep"`. It's not what I wanted, but works for now...